# Where to put Flutter AJAX?

Tags: flutter

I come from the web dev world.  I have designed a Flutter app that needs to grab some JSON from the web very early on.  I want my first screen to show up, and while it is being drawn, behind the scenes I want the JSON fetch to happen.  There is a start button on Page 1 that will be disabled until the JSON is fetched. (But Page 1 will have some text info to keep the reader engaged until the fetch happens.)

Where would I stick the JSON fetch?  Can I put it in initState of Page 1? Or can I initiate a call at the very start of main at the root of the app?  Or somewhere else?

FWIW I use Provider for state management, if that helps?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Take a look for cookbook https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: Thanks, @Kerim, I am taking a look now!

Answer (score 0):

Calling it in the initState is best since your widgets still build. Since there will be a state change, make sure you use a stateful widget. Also, don't forget to call setState to re-enable the button. Example code:

```
  class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
    const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
  }

  class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      jsonFetch();
    }
    void jsonFetch() {
      // your functionality here
      // on complete call:
    /*
     setState(() {
       isJsonFetched = true;
     });
     */
    }

    void doSomethingOnPressed(){
      // Your functionality here
    }

    bool isJsonFetched = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              isJsonFetched 
                  ? doSomethingOnPressed() 
                  :null;
            },
            child: Text('Press Me')
          )
        )
      );
    }
  }
```